# Does a dwarven rogue with dwarf rogue substitution levels 1 and 3 gain +3d6 sneak attack on (standard) rogue level 5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, rogue, sneak-attack, dwarf

This question is closely related and a follow-up to [the question whether dwarf rogue substitution levels 1 and 3 incur a loss of sneak attack damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/85036/do-the-dwarf-rogue-substitution-levels-1-and-3-incur-a-loss-of-sneak-attack-dama). The accepted answer was that dwarf rogue substitution levels 1 and 3 do not grant sneak attacks, thus a dwarf rogue with these substitution levels would get the demolitionist ability (extra damage against constructs) but no sneak attack.

But the entry in Table 3-15, PHB p. 49, for rogue 5 is: "sneak attack +3d6". If a dwarf rogue took the substitution levels 1 and 3 - would he get the full sneak attack at standard rogue level 5?

Answer (score 2):

## No

To substitute means to take something out and put something else in it's place. If at level 5 you'd gain +3d6 sneak attack, you don't substitute... you just add. Why would anybody ever take standard rogue levels 1 and 3?

I cannot cite any raw, since substitution levels from magazines aren't RAW anyway, but common sense says he'd get +1d6 if taking a level granting better sneak attack after his substitution levels.

PHB pg50

> **Sneak Attack**: If a rogue can catch an opponent when he is unable to defend himself effectively from her attack, she can strike a vital
> spot for extra damage. Basically, the rogue’s attack deals extra
> damage any time her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC
> (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when
> the rogue flanks her target. This extra damage is 1d6 at 1st level,
> and **it increases by 1d6 every two rogue levels thereafter.** Should
> the rogue score a critical hit with a sneak attack, this extra damage
> is not multiplied.

Increases, doesn't become 3d6 at 5th level.

Comment: RE: "…since substitution levels from magazines aren't RAW anyway…" It might be useful *either* to expand upon that point if you think it's a necessary point *or* omit it if it's not. (I think the latter would be better, but it's your call.)

Comment: "Why would anybody ever take standard rogue levels 1 and 3" - first, because she is not a dwarf, second because it **at least** postpones the sneak attack. "To substitute means to take something out and put something else in its place" sounds reasonable,  but e.g. "Generalist Wizardry" elf wizard substitution level 1 just adds to the *non-specialized* wizard without any cost. I would certainly prefer RAW, though I think the quote you cited might be the base for such: Isn't there a general rule that text trumps tables?

Comment: @Giorin Sort of. [Here's the text trumps table thing.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56815/8610)